# Errors while iterating and processing the split string in recursive functions

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Let's say we have a string

```
"+x1 +x2 -x3
+x4      +x5 -x6
..."
```

and a type formula:

```
type formula =
  | Bot
  | Top
  | Atom of string
  | Imp of (formula * formula)
  | Or of (formula * formula)
  | And of (formula * formula)
  | Not of formula

let atom x = Atom x
```

(aka predicate logic)
and we want to:

Create a function which takes **one** line, splits it and turns it into disjunction using the formula type. (sort of like Or(Atom "x1", Atom "x2", Not Atom "x3") if we give the first line as an input)

I've written this:

```
let string_to_disj st =
  let lst = Str.split (Str.regexp " \t") st in
  let rec total lst = 
    match lst with
    | [] -> Or (Bot, Bot) (*Is this correct btw?*)
    | h :: t -> Or (string_to_lit h, total t);;
```

where

```
let string_to_lit = 
  match String.get s 0 with
  | '+' -> atom (String.sub s 1 (String.length s-1))
  | '-' -> Not(atom(String.sub s 1 (String.length s-1)))
  | _ -> atom(s);;
```

However, `string_to_disj` raises a syntax error at line

```
| h :: t -> Or (string_to_lit h, total t)
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Bot and Top btw, is a way of calling false and true.

Comment: I would expect the empty disjunction to be `Bot` or nothing at all rather than `Or(Bot, Bot)`. (And the `atom` function seems unnecessary.)

Answer (score 2):

You have `let rec total lst` but you have no matching `in`. Every `let` requires a matching `in`. (Except at the top level of a module where it is for defining exported symbols of the module).

Also note that you are defining a function named `total` but you have no calls to the function except the one recursive call.